# I don't like the new design on the CVs

Tags: feature-request, design, developer-story

I don't like the header on the new design. This kind of centered header is one of the worst trends in web design at the moment:

- Centered text looks like badly-formatted poetry
- For a job site, emphasizing someone's visual appearance over everything else as the first thing that a potential employer sees is really bad, especially with the current diversity problem in tech.
- Emphasizing photos so strongly at the top like that looks like it's trying to appeal to narcissistic tendencies.

Gitlab does a similar thing with the design, and it's the main reason that I stopped using Gitlab.

Please don't do that with the header.

The rest of the thumbnail looks fine.

[image]

Comment: Not that many IT firms looking for handsome poets, then?

Comment: *This kind of centered header is one of the worst trends in web design at the moment.* That's the problem with trends, they can't suit everyone. On the other hand, they also change a lot, so you may expect this to change within 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Everything old is new again; welcome back to 1995.

Comment: Trends change a lot, but some of them should never get off the ground.

Comment: This design does not trigger my OCD.

Comment: Maybe you don't live in an area/industry with severe diversity problems. There shouldn't be so much emphasis on physical appearance on a job site.

Comment: I don't understand the diversity argument here. A 16x16 Gravatar in conjunction with the name are usually enough to guess a person’s skin colour, nationality, and gender, no? If an employer is less likely to consider you because of one of those, they’re going to do so no matter how big the image with your face is on the CV. It’s not right to draw out the big political guns to support your personal dislike of a design choice

Comment: @Pekka웃 There a difference between not accepting a CV and turning someone down at interview based on diversity issues. I do agree with your point though.

Comment: I agree. it's a hideous design.

Comment: It's not that there is a photo there -- it's this new trend to create a pyramid on top of the page with the profile picture as the main point of focus. Design is not meaningless. There are 42 upvotes already, so I'm not the only one who dislikes it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it isn't already I would like to see the photo as optional/removable.

Whilst diversity is never really an issue for me, I deliberately never include a photo with a CV.

I have even withdrew an application for one firm who insisted I include a photo with my application.

Additionally, I think having my normal Gravatar is also not something I would include on a CV.

*Note: This is an issue with the current system too.*

Comment: On the current system if you edit the top block (where your name is) there is an option to uncheck Gravatar. For me, that removes the profile pic from the public CV.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up! The Developer Story has been in a limited private beta for a while now and getting fresh eyes on it will bring new feedback that is much appreciated.

#### Left aligned vs Centered aligned design

The Developer Story is our evolution of the traditional CV in a new format. It’s difficult to say if a left-aligned would be better than a centered aligned design. Considering it’s been in a limited private beta, we’d like to let the entire community test out the design before revamping it based on a screenshot in an email. The Developer Story should be available to everyone soon and we’re anticipating a lot of feedback on it, and we will adapt the layout if needed.

#### Privacy Avatar Issue

Your second issue is surrounding privacy and diversity, and the avatar on the Developer Story. We take privacy and diversity issues very seriously when it comes to your information, and I appreciate you bringing this to our attention.

Right now on your Developer Story you can:

- use a different avatar, instead of the one on your profile
- hide your Developer Story to the community

We don’t currently have a feature to let you apply without an avatar but we’re definitely open to changing that. In fact, we’re thinking about allowing users to use their [default Stack Overflow avatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated) that is generated during signup to apply, or even applying without the avatar all together.

Either one of these would address the concern of using your profile pic when applying, but we’re open to other suggestions as well.

Additionally, If you want to be even more involved in the creation of the Developer Story, we're always looking for candidates to help us doing user research (feel free to contact me on [twitter](https://twitter.com/stephane_m_))

Comment: *Post ends with e-mail address, possible spam* ;)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I replaced it with twitter :p

Comment: "or even applying without the avatar all together" - wait, this wasn't an option before? That surprises me -- what possible need could a company have to see your face? They don't even know that it is your face. And resumes don't have a slot for your face at the top...

Comment: "It’s difficult to say if a left-aligned would be better than a centered aligned design" -> No it's not. Try reading four paragraphs of centre aligned text; it significantly hampers readability because every line starts at a different location. It's only suitable for brief snippets of text (2-3 lines). This is typography 101.

Comment: It's live now, and all of my comments still apply to "story view".

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - exactly.