# Developer story description is centered

Tags: bug, design, developer-story

Compare traditional and story view:
[image]
[image]
The same text, both supporting markdown, but some markdown items (lists, code, tables) are not compatible with center-alignment. In general center-aligning user-written paragraphs are not a good idea unless you know it's 1-2 sentences.

Comment: Very well said.  I don't use the story view just because of this.

Comment: Also mentioned at: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335156/660921

Answer (score 13):

We're currently working on a design that'll use a left align alignment. That said, we can't just left align one element on the page, everything has to be left aligned, that's why it takes a little bit of work.

If you're interested in seeing an early prototype and give feedback on it, feel free to contact me on [twitter](https://twitter.com/stephane_m_).

Comment: This is still not fixed as of May 2019, right?

Comment: Will you fix this? It looks ridiculous, unprofessional.